# cuda algorithm structure

Tags: c++, c, algorithm, cuda

I would like to understand the general way of doing the following on a GPU using CUDA.

I have an algorithm that might look something like this:

```
void DoStuff(int[,] inputMatrix, int[,] outputMatrix)
{
   forloop {
     forloop {
         if (something) {
                DoStuffA(inputMatrix,a,b,c,outputMatrix)
         }
         else {
               DoStuffB(inputMatrix,a,b,c,outputMatrix)
         }
     }
   }
}
```

DoStuffA and DoStuffB are simple paralleizable functions (e.g. doing a matrix row operation) that the CUDA examples have plenty of.

What I want to do is to know how to put the main algorithm "DoStuff" onto the GPU and then call DoStuffA and DoStuffB as and when I need to (and they execute in parallel). i.e. the outer loop part is single threaded, but the inner calls are not.

The examples I have seen seem to be multithreaded from the get-go. I assume there is a way to just call a single GPU based method from the outside world and have it control all of the parallel bits by itself?

Comment: What are the forloops? Are they simple iterators over the input, or something more complex. And is the condition (something) constant for a single call of DoStuff, or does it depend on the state of output matrix?

Comment: no the forloops are not simple iterators and the condition is complex too. In summary I realise I could have the "DoStuff" method running on the CPU and then call the GPU for DoStuffA and DoStuffB many times however I want to avoid the copying of the matrices from CPU to GPU repeatedly - i.e by putting DoStuff on the GPU.

Comment: Could you edit the details into your question? This is a pretty abstract question and it is going to be very difficult to answer constructively. Don't think about threads, think about data parallel work. Kernels running on the GPU can only do data parallel work, they can't dispatch new work or run other kernels. So typically, the "inner" foreach loops get run on the GPU, and "outer" loops containing convergence tests or similar on the host. Try keeping that in mind when refining the question, right now your understanding of the execution model sounds a bit sketchy.

Comment: I think your comment answered my question well. Many thanks. Basically you are saying that in general for algorithms the outer part of the algo (with all its decisions etc) gets done on CPU and trivially parallizable bit gets done on the GPU.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It depends on how the data inter relates to each other in the for loops, but roughly I would

1. Pack all input matrices into a block of memory
2. Upload input matrices
3. Do for loops on CPU, calling kernels for DoStuffA and DoStuffB
4. Download output matrices in one block

This way, the biggest problem is overhead for calling each kernel. If your input data is large then it won't be so bad.